# unable to execute powershell command through java?

Tags: java, powershell, cmd

I am trying to run a powershell command which starts the tomcat service.Currently the command is working perfectly when executed directly through the windows powershell. However if i run the same command from java i get and error saying

```
Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'net'.
```

my powershell command is:

```
Start-Process -verb runas cmd -ArgumentList "/k net start Tomcat7"
```

my java code:

```
final String PS_COMMAND = " powershell.exe  Start-Process -verb runas cmd -ArgumentList /k net start Tomcat7   " ;
Process p=  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(PS_COMMAND);
 BufferedReader BR=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
             String l;
             while((l=BR.readLine()) != null){
                 System.out.print(l);
             }
```

Comment: Does it help if you wrap the arguments in single quotes: `-ArgumentList '/k net start Tomcat7'`

Comment: In your java string you didn't write the quotes around `/k net start Tomcat7`, so the only value associated with `-Argumentlist` is `/k` and then powershell wonders what it should do with the rest of the params.

Comment: @ boxdog omg!! thank you sooo much!! its working finally!!

Answer (score 0):

I see now you're using `-verb runas` to force a UAC prompt if needed.

In that case, it's a good approach but at least you can remove the `cmd.exe` indirection. The reason it isn't working as is though is really just because you didn't quote the values you're passing to the `-ArgumentList` parameter.

Try this:

```java
final String PS_COMMAND = "powershell.exe Start-Process -verb runas net.exe -ArgumentList 'start Tomcat7'" ;
```

---

You are complicating things too much. There's no reason to run `powershell.exe` to run `cmd.exe` to run `net.exe`.

You should do one of the following:

Run PowerShell's command:

```java
final String PS_COMMAND = "powershell.exe Start-Service Tomcat7" ;
```

Or run `net.exe` directly:

```java
final String PS_COMMAND = "net.exe start Tomcat7" ;
```